# How to Move All Tables Based on Schema (Sql Server 2012)

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have a question.  I am currently working on a SQL project for my class, and I am a bit of a SQL beginner.  During one part of my project I am to move  all of the schemas to new filegroups from a database.

If I understand correctly from researching for the past several days, I am to use the SELECT name FROM sys.schemas statement to find all the schemas in a database, take the associated tables with the schemas, and move them to a new filegroup.

Ok, I know how to move a table to a new filegroup, and how indexes are used in that process.  What I am confused about is how to use a SELECT statement or other statement to call ALL of the tables within a specific schema to move them.  The database we use is huge (adventureworks), so I am not sure the answer was to move each table individually.

I have researched for several days, looked through my text, and my student adviser has been less than helpful.  I am honestly not even sure where to start.  I have searched how to move specific indexes, tables, etc.. into other filegroups.  Like I said, I am very much a beginner in this, and I am mainly looking for direction and examples.  Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I would first identify all the tables and then copy this data over, table by table. I'm assuming you can find the table from the master table, and then can recreate a new table from that identifier? After you do that, you can move the data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any bulk process to do this.  I would build a list of tables to move, iterate over that list, and move them one-by-one.  This might involve a cursor (do they teach you about cursors, do they give you dire warnings against their use, do they explain why?), or some form of do-it-yourself list.

Comment: No they have not taught us about cursors.  I know about cursors from a previous project because that was the only way I could complete it.  I can create the list of tables with a select statement utilizing a LIKE statement since all the schema is based on prefix. I am not sure what the SQL query code would be to iterate through each table to move it.  Especially if I have to differentiate between non-clustered and clustered indexes correct?

Comment: Under the circumstances, stick with a cursor. You'd need to join sys.tables to sys.indexes to figure out if it's a heap or a clustered index (hint: where index_id < 2) and, within the cursor loop, process the table accordingly.